# Manipulating the double quotes when creating a request with python dumps

Tags: python, json

Looking for some advice customizing requests for json style syntax.

`json.dumps` will format the like this:

```
{"tenantid": 1, "name": "NewRoleName", "users": "[djones]"}
```

But the servers wants something like this:

```
{"tenantid": 1, "name": "NewRoleName", "users": ["djones"]}
```

Any easy way to manipulate the double quotes to be placed with in the square brackets?

```
payload = {}
funcURL = "roles"
if name          is not None: payload.update({'name': name})
if userStore     is not None: payload.update({'userStore': userStore})
if users         is not None: payload.update({'users': "[" + users + "]"})
if tenantid      is not None: payload.update({'tenantid': tenantid})
if permissions   is not None: payload.update({'userClaims': permissions})
print users
print payload
payload = json.dumps(payload)
return self._call_url('POST', funcURL, payload)
```

`_call_url` uses requests to send the payload out:

```
response = requests.request( methodType, baseURL + "/" + funcURL, data=payload, headers=self.headers, timeout=timeout, verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
if users         is not None: payload.update({'users': users})
```

This should work if `users` is something like `users = ["djones","mjones","todd"]`

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets denote a list. So you have to put `users` into a list:

```
funcURL = "roles"
payload = {}
if name is not None:
    payload['name'] = name
if userStore is not None:
    payload['userStore'] = userStore
if users is not None:
    payload['users'] = [users]
if tenantid is not None:
    payload['tenantid'] = tenantid
if permissions is not None:
    payload['userClaims'] = permissions
payload = json.dumps(payload)
return self._call_url('POST', funcURL, payload)
```